# Retrieving the value of the PHP --with-config-file-scan-dir switch

Tags: php

I need to return the path of folder configured via the --with-config-file-scan-dir switch for a particular PHP implementation.

I can achieve this by writing bash code something like:

```
folder=$(php --ini                                         \
        | grep "Scan for additional .ini files in:"        \
        | cut -d" " -f7       \
        )
```

But the above approach seems inexact and potentially error prone.

My preference would be to do something like the following:

```
folder=$(php -r 'print ini_get("with-config-file-scan-dir config option");')
```

but I can't seem to find the necessary configuration option name.

I would greatly appreciate some guru input on this if you have it!

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the value in a php-script or in bash? Is it set for a php command or in php.ini?

Comment: @Seb - ultimately I will be using in bash but I don't mind whether I retrieve from within php and pass it out to bash or directly from bash, as long as it is reliable. I'm not sure I understand your second question 100%  but the switch in question is set as part of the ./configure (php pre-make) statement when building the php environment

Comment: @Pancho What you are doing is perfect. There is no other way of doing it. (Saying this after debugging the build process and checking the internal usage of that config option in PHP's source code)

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl - a pity that there doesn't seem to be a cleaner way :( oh well

Comment: @Pancho This is because of the nature of the GNU build system. Options passed to `./configure` will go to `confg.h` as `C` pre-processor constants. When the C program is getting compiled those constants will getting replaced by their values. `php --ini` is using the constant directly so the output is indeed the value of that `configure` option. You need only be aware of the fact that if the options had been omitted, the outputted value by `php --ini` will be the string `<none>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-config-file-scan-dir).

```
php -r "echo PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php

```
<?php
if ($filelist = php_ini_scanned_files()) {
    if (strlen($filelist) > 0) {
        $files = explode(',', $filelist);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo "<li>" . trim($file) . "</li>\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Actually, the code above would print all the scanned files... If you just want the dir, maybe substr the first element found?

```
<?php
if ($filelist = php_ini_scanned_files()) {
    if (strlen($filelist) > 0) {
        $files = explode(',', $filelist);
        $dir = substr($files[0],0,strrpos($files[0],"/")+1);
        echo $dir;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input! I'm really hoping someone will identify a configuration parameter that will allow the writing of a one-line "get-the-value" statement letting PHP perform the logic needed to retrieve a value it must have readily available at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return values of

```
php_ini_loaded_file()
```

or

```
php_ini_scanned_files()
```

Not shure what exactly you're looking for. The first one gives the path to the loaded php.ini file. The second one gets the paths and filenames for additional loaded config files. You might need to extra the directory names with dirname(). Might not be a one liner, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much @Seb. The php_ini_scanned_files() is close to what I'm after, as it lists all the files in the directory I am looking for. So grabbing the first line of the return and dropping the file name and trailing comma would work ...but will still take work to parse reliably so I'm not sure whether it offers an improvement on my original approach above. Thanks again, I really appreciate your insights on this.